# phpmyadmin displays blank screen

Tags: phpmyadmin, wamp

phpmyadmin was working just fine now when I try to run it, it loads the page for a bit then displays a completely blank screen. Any suggestions?

Comment: Undo what you did to break it.

Comment: Try http://superuser.com

Answer (score 1):

Without nothing more specific I would say:

> Turn your error_reporting to E_ALL, if
>   still a blank screen check your
>   error_logs

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have a global 'X-Frame-Options' policy in effect which may be blocking the frames...

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a port 80 problem. Check out step by step instructions on this zac1987's blog
http://ye5.blogspot.com/2011/01/wamp-server-localhost-shows-blank-page.html

Anything using Port 80 will screw up WAMP.
Uninstall Skype.

This question may have been answered here:
[WAMP server shows a blank page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4386404/wamp-server-shows-a-blank-page)

- Font21

Comment: There is no need to uninstall Skype, just to make WAMP work. Just (1) quit Skype, (2) start WAMP, and then (3) open Skype. Also, there are alternatives to WAMP, like XAMPP, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a long time after the fact, but people may still have this problem and look at this response (I know I did):  In Windows 8, the program has to be run as a administrator.  Otherwise, you will see the above problem.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript needs to be enabled for phpMyAdmin to work.

Kindly check if JavaScript is disabled in your browser (e.g. testing if your web pages work with it turned off).

Issue reproducible on:

- phpMyAdmin: Version information: 4.1.14, latest stable version: 4.7.3
- WampServer Version 2.5
- Firefox Developer Edition: 55.0b13 (64 bit)
- Windows 8: Version 6.3
  (Build 9600)