# WAMP server shows a blank page

Tags: wamp, wampserver

MY WAMP server has broken down.

http://localhost

shows a blank page.
any help please?

Comment: I think skype might be the reason

Comment: visit this : http://ye5.blogspot.com/2011/01/wamp-server-localhost-shows-blank-page.html Solution is here....

Comment: Every answer just mentions skype. But I don't have Skype and I have problems. I am using windows 8...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had to use system recover at the end and the problem was at the skype, i tried to uncheck the "use port 80" box under skypes options but the only way to do it properly is to recover ur pc at an earlier date.

Mind you becareful and make a copy of your data first

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem. It was skype, I had already unchecked the "use port 80" box under skype options but apparently skype was still running on port 80. I followed the advice at http://ye5.blogspot.com/2011/01/wamp-server-localhost-shows-blank-page.html and it showed that skype was the problem and how to force the process to stop running. Then wampserver worked beautifully.

Comment: Thank you so much! The problem was Skype for me too.

Answer (score 4):

For those who only have skype installed (no other applications hogging port 80), a temporary workaround is to quit your skype, then start your WAMPServer, then only start your skype. Just my 2 sents.

Answer (score 3):

Same issue, here is the solution !

**Cause :**

Another program (Skype but not only) is using the port80 (which is by default the one used by wamp).
You can see it typing the following command "netstat -ano" and looking what is on "localadress 0.0.0.0.80", if you want to see the concerned program open, note the number at the end of the line (4 for example), then open taskmanager, services, and see who is on PID 4.

**Solution :**

Let's **change wamp port to 81** !

[Change wamp port from 80 to 81](http://xfloyd.net/blog/?p=515)

Answer (score 2):

I changed the WAMP PHP version from 5.6 to 7.04 and it worked like a charm. Give it a shot!

Go to > Notification Area > Wamp Icon > PHP > Versions

Answer (score 1):

Enable error reporting in the configuration so that you can see why.

Comment: Thank you. I ended up with a php.ini error that popped up out of nowhere. http://stackoverflow.com/a/32901489/2407742

Answer (score 1):

Not only skype will cause the problem, all other software that using port 80 will cause the same problem such as anti-virus, online movie player... if you want to know how to check which software is using port 80, and how to delete it. Please follow the 7 steps that shown on my blog : **http://ye5.blogspot.com/2011/01/wamp-server-localhost-shows-blank-page.html**

Answer (score 0):

Okay so looking at both responses here and elsewhere, many people have been saying to quit skype or whichever process is running port 80. I used this link http://ye5.blogspot.com/2011/01/wamp-server-localhost-shows-blank-page.html as provided by zac1987 to locate what was interfering via port 80.

However, many people still complained that locating and quitting the program taking up port 80 didn't work straight away. In my case I just had to wait a minute or two for all of the Skype processes to close themselves and *then* I restarted WAMP Server and it is now working fine.

Hope this helps somebody :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I successfull solved it.

First I can saw only blank screen. When I click on *Wampserver* icon then it show me information about "*Server is Offline*". I click "*Put Online*" and server changed to online.

Next, I closed Skype and through *Wampserver* icon I check that 80 port is free:

```
Wampserver icon -> Apache -> Service -> Test Port 80
```

At this time my browser showing me webpage about `can't open localhost`.

Next, I install apache service: `Wampserver icon -> Apache -> Service -> Install Service`

After installed I start service: `Wampserver icon -> Apache -> Service -> Start/Resume Service`

If service start correctly then menu option "*Start/Resume Service*" is shadow.

Now my webbrowser correctly show localhost webpage.

Additionally in my Skype, I unchecked option "*Use port 80 and 443 as alternatives for incoming connections*".

Answer (score 0):

I too have the same but i changed the listen port of wamp server to 5050 its works for me and we use skype at port 80 itself. for changing the listen port go to the folder were the wamp server installed. if you are using the windows go to the following path.

**C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\conf** in that folder find the **httpd.conf file** open that file any editor and change the listen port 5050.

**#Listen 12.34.56.78:5050**

**Listen 0.0.0.0:5050**

**Listen [::0]:5050**

Answer (score 0):

The cause on my server was a php.ini error on line 107.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/32901489/2407742

I commented out line 107 because it was unnecessary and restarted WAMP.