# WampServer... Blank localhost and phpmyadmin pages

Tags: phpmyadmin, wamp

I am trying to use my local server to test and develop Wordpress themes. I already have wamp installed, as I used it when I was developing a previous project (not Wordpress). How do I remove this site from wamp, and point the server to my Wordpress installation?

One of the issues is that localhost and phpmyadmin both load blank pages. I have verified that port 80 is indeed being used by wampapache.

I got the following error:

> ( ! ) Warning: mysqli_connect() [function.mysqli-connect]: [2002] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not (trying to connect via tcp://172.20.1.63:3306) in C:\Users***************************\lib\ezdb\classes\ezmysqlidb.php on line 135

The file path points to my previous project in Eclipse

This is line 135:

```
$connection = mysqli_connect( $server, $user, $password, null, (int)$port, $socketPath );
```

Comment: So I can't seem to find any info on my problem. I just created another wamp installation in a different folder. That way, I can start fresh...

Comment: Now, I get the localhost page but am also getting a MySQL error: Error

MySQL said: Documentation
#1045 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
phpMyAdmin tried to connect to the MySQL server, and the server rejected the connection. You should check the host, username and password in your configuration and make sure that they correspond to the information given by the administrator of the MySQL server.

Comment: I set a password in the config.inc.php file $cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = ''; and I now have the phpmyadmin start page

Answer (score 1):

I gather a bug in PHPMyAdmin 3.5.1 caused this on some versions of Safari (including Safari 5 Windows). This issue was fixed in 3.5.2 (apparently). An alternative fix (that worked for me) is to add the following line to config.inc.php:

```
 $cfg['AllowThirdPartyFraming'] = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

On the WAMP Wordpress site:
Dashboard > Tools > export >  All content > click download export file

On the target site:
Dashboard > Tools > import >  Wordpress > Choose file > upload and import

About the blank pages, that still sounds like a port 80 problem. Even if you've verified that port 80 is indeed being used by wampapache, other apps might be "fighting" to gain access. Check out step by step instructions on this zac1987's blog
http://ye5.blogspot.com/2011/01/wamp-server-localhost-shows-blank-page.html

Anything using Port 80 will screw up WAMP. Uninstall Skype.

This question may have been answered here:
[WAMP server shows a blank page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4386404/wamp-server-shows-a-blank-page)

- Font21
  http://DavidFontenotPhotography.com