# WampServer gives me blank page on the browser

Tags: wamp, wampserver

I have installed WampServer. It is online now. When I give localhost in the browser it gives me a blank page. How can I get rid of it?

Before installing WampServer, Do i need to install PHP manually?

Comment: check contents of index.php file in www directory

Comment: Checked it. Do I need to update/add anything? Can you tell me in detail?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A better solution would be to use
wampmanager -> Apache -> Service -> Test port 80

This will launch a command window and tell you if anything is using port 80.

Then rather than killing it ( if its a service that is automatically started it will just be back again after a reboot ) attempt to reconfigure it so it no longer uses port 80.

Comment: A similar option is to configure apache to use a different port. Open the configuration file:  wampmanager -> Apache -> httpd.conf 
and replace 80 by any other number (e.g. 81). Now, instead of "localhost" you must use "localhost:81". For instance when opening phpMyAdmin, the address is. http://localhost:81/phpmyadmin

Comment: @CarlosBorau Yes you can do that, but then you hae to use the port number on every url, which most eventually find very annoying

Comment: @CarlosBorau Did you identify what it was that was using port 80? Most things can be reconfigured with a little thought and googling

Comment: Your port 80 is actually used by: Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
(on Windows 10). Thanks for your interest!

Comment: So that is Microsofts IIS, also a web server, W10 likes to instal it by default. If you are not using it, uninstall it. If you use that as well, I assume you dont use IIS and Apache at the same time. So you could just stop IIS while you use Apache,

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue - my W icon was also not green during the whole time.

I exited Skype and then selected the Wamp icon and selected "Restart Services".

W turned green, localhost working now.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it.

`Goto --> command prompt-> type netstat -aon`
and check the PID for port 80. for eg "**333**"

Then `Goto --> Task Manager --> processes` find the PID 333 and kill it. Then goto Wampserver and Restart All Services. Then it will work

Answer (score 1):

This issue occurs when port 80 is occupied by some other service.
There are multiple applications which can occupy port 80 (Not limited to Skype).
I ran into this problem on Windows 10, port 80 was occupied by IIS 10.
Following solved it for me:

1. Check which service is using port 80 (It was IIS 10 for me)
2. Go to Services (Search for it in start menu)
3. Look for 'World Wide Web Publishing Services'
4. Stop it
5. Go to its properties and change start up type to 'Manual'
6. Restart all services in Wamp

This should help when you do not want to change apache port and keep it simple.

Answer (score 0):

Check out step by step instructions on this guys blog
http://ye5.blogspot.com/2011/01/wamp-server-localhost-shows-blank-page.html

Anything using Port 80 will screw up WAMP.
Use task manager to kill Skype before each time you use WAMP or XAMP. Or, just uninstall Skype.

This question may have been answered here:
[WAMP server shows a blank page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4386404/wamp-server-shows-a-blank-page)

Answer (score 0):

I initially installed WAMP on my D Drive as I didn't want it to take from my very little memory on the C drive.. then I thought "let me try still installing in on the C drive"
Then it worked and the localhost doesn't show blank anymore :)
Cheers,
Ani

Answer (score 0):

Start > Run > services.msc > disable "World Wide Publishing" and restart all wamp