# WAMP localhost page is empty

Tags: php, apache, localhost

My localhost page is just empty. I wanted the wamp server home page to appear. I've seen in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4386404/wamp-server-shows-a-blank-page) that this problem may occur due to Skype. I've stopped Skype from my processes and still getting the problem.

Since the following site is very frequently mentioned in similar posts, I visited it:

http://ye5.blogspot.com/2011/01/wamp-server-localhost-shows-blank-page.html

I tried their solution of identifying the process ID of those process which are using port:80. I found out that the only process that is using port:80 is Apache Server itself.

I also went to wampmanager -> Apache -> Service -> Test port 80 and this test reconfirmed that only Apache is using port:80.

It's driving me nuts, this problem. If Skype is turned off, if no process is using port:80 other than Apache itself, what else can be the reason behind this?

My OS is Windows 7, IIS is turned off, I have CodeIgniter installed and if I write `localhost/CI` then I get the CodeIgniter home page. But if I write `localhost` only, then a blank page appears.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be try turn off port :80 Skype follow here:

In Skype windows:
Options > Advanced > Connection 
Then uncheck "Use port 80 and 443 for additional incomming connections"

May be help you!

Comment: I'm afraid this is not going to help, as I've already done this. Still no luck.

Comment: Does having a 'child process' of Apache sound normal? Because I found that Apache was creating child process each time I start the service.

Comment: 1 reason sometime my friend can't run Apache that his language pc that not support UTF8, change language for US or UK default, Apache run.

Comment: verify and make sure you have an index file in your htdocs directory