# Blank frames in phpmyadmin

Tags: phpmyadmin

I installed phpmyadmin on nginx and used certbot for letsencrypt certificates.

I can log into phpmyadmin and see the standard menus, but the main area/frame where I would manage a database is blank and the menu on the left briefly shows a list of my databases but then disappears.

There are no errors in the nginx log or the browser console.

phpmyadmin has $cfg['ForceSSL'] = true

Comment: [ForceSSL](https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html?highlight=forcessl#cfg_ForceSSL) is decprecated: "Deprecated since version 4.6.0: This setting is no longer available since phpMyAdmin 4.6.0. Please adjust your webserver instead."

Comment: For the blank screens, more info is needed, see: [phpmyadmin displays blank screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383545/phpmyadmin-displays-blank-screen)

Comment: The problem isnt a blank screen as main menus are displayed, its information about the databases that is not displayed e.g. no list of databases in left menu, do database info in main frame. Digging down into the html code in the browser, I see "<![CDATA[ var debugSQLInfo = 'null'; // ]]>" where there would be database info. Javascript is enabled.

Comment: The list of databases is also empty when visiting `http://localhost/phpmyadmin/index.php?route=/server/databases` ? (Did you check username/password fro database access?)

Comment: Any hints in the webserver error log? Everything showing then disappearing is quite strange, though. Can you also try in a different browser?

Comment: Hey, digging into nginx logs i just spotted:  SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:141CF06C:SSL routines:tls_parse_ctos_key_share:bad key share) while SSL handshaking, client: x.x.x.x , server: 0.0.0.0:443
I dont think its a login problem as I can login to phpmyadmin and this issue happens after login. I double checked permissions for the account in MariaDB.